# Having trouble with x axis date in line chart (pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

This seems very simple and I am not sure why it's not working. It works fine when I use a stacked bar chart, but when I use a line chart the formatting is not correct (or something else is not working?). For example, the stacked barchart looks like
[image]

Very simple logic to create the above chart:

```
pivot_df = base_df.pivot(index='date', columns='column10', values='values')
pivot_df1 = pivot_df.fillna(0)
pivot_df1 = pivot_df1.astype(float)
pivot_df1 = pivot_df1.plot.bar(stacked=True, figsize=(10,7))
```

Now I am trying to create a line chart using the same base dataset (so same dates) but slightly different columns/values. I filter the dataset on one condition and remove a few columns (not sure if this is causing the issue?).

```
base_df1 = base_df[((base_df['filter_column'] == 'this'))]
base_df1 = base_df1[['date', 'column2', 'column3', 'column4']]
base_df1 = base_df1.fillna(0)
base_df1 = base_df1.astype(float) 
base_df1_piv = base_df1.pivot_table(index='date',columns='column2', values = 'column3')
base_df1_piv.plot.line()
```

[image: x axis date issue]

I feel like I am missing something very obvious? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It is much easier to help you if you can include sample data in your dataframe for `base_df`. Please see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples

Comment: I could venture a guess, but without a minimum reproducible example it's hard to know if the guess is right.